# What does an orange street symbolize in Waze?

Tags: navigation, waze

I wonder what an orange street symbolizes in Waze. Example in Washington state, USA:

[image]

Traffic jam? No traffic jam, but slow street? Something else? I believe the traffic jams I've seen on Waze were red, not orange.

Comment: So found this: https://support.google.com/waze/partners/answer/7246755?hl=en#zippy=%2Cwaze-o-meter Open the Waze-o-Meter tab for color definitions.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks! Great find. You are welcome to post it as an answer! "Light red" no wonder why I couldn't find it when searching for orange on Google.

Comment: What I find weird are those darker gradient things on the line that are sort of arrow-shaped, which to me would indicate that it's a one-way road, and you're going the wrong way.  I'm sure that's not what it is, but it could be read that way.  Seems a slightly problematic choice in terms of UI design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found: https://support.google.com/waze/partners/answer/7246755?hl=en#zippy=%2Cwaze-o-meter

And as you noted in the comment the description of colors may not match expectations. As that page is for Waze Partners, I'm unclear as to its support in various regions, YMMV.

From the webpage on **Use Traffic View**:

> **Waze-o-Meter**
>
> The color coding of the Waze-o-Meter mirrors what's displayed on the Waze app.
>
> - **Green:** Free Flow - Great conditions, cars are able to move at speed limit.
> - **Yellow:** Light Traffic - Slight congestion, but drivers can still travel at relative speeds.
> - **Light red:** Moderate Traffic - Congestion starting to build up noticeably.
> - **Red:** Heavy Traffic - Speeds have slowed down, expect significant delays.
> - **Dark red:** Bumper to Bumper - Traffic is near standstill.

Comment: I still don't understand what orange *or* purple are supposed to represent, because neither of those is listed in the color coding key...

Comment: Orange isn't orange, Waze calls it "Light Red" and purple is just the default route, from: https://www.waze.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=1500144#:~:text=The%20default%20route%20is%20in,being%20tracked%20by%20someone%20else.

Comment: Ah, thanks.... silly me I saw #ff9752 in the above screenshot and it didn't occur to me that it was what #f26a54 was referring to on the linked page.